# I can't web scrape scrape tr tags of a table using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the proxy list of this site : http://cool-proxy.net/
However i can't find the tr tags with the class of "proxy-row ng-scope"

here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://cool-proxy.net/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text , 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table')
rows =table.find_all('tr', class_='proxy-row ng-scope')
print(rows)
```

Comment: If you view the source of the page, only the "proxy-row" class is there and there is only one of them. The page is using javascript to load the actual rows. Therefore when you load the page through the request, you are not actually getting the data you see on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to get just, api url with all of the json, like:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://cool-proxy.net/proxies.json').json()

all_ips = [{pr['country_name']: pr['ip']} for pr in response]

print(all_ips)
```

I get only country_name, and ip, but there're all of the other keys what you want, like:

```
import requests

response = requests.get('http://cool-proxy.net/proxies.json').json()

all_ips = [{'country': pr['country_name'], 'ip': pr['ip'], 'port': pr['port']} for pr in response]

print(all_ips)
```